# remove T and Z in date field in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, utc

I have this date field in UTC format say

```
dt1 = "2020-03-27T16:59:57Z"
```

and another date field in local format say

```
dt2 = "2020-03-27 16:00:00"
```

I need to find the differnece in minutes between dt1 and dt2. Basically I need to remove the **T** and **Z** in dt1 datefield and do the difference.

Here is what I tried:

```
var diff = (dt1 - dt2) / 1000;
           diff /= 60;
          return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));
```

But it return NaN as output. please provide a fix for this!

Comment: There is no "UTC format". UTC is a time standard, it doesn't define a format. Perhaps you mean ISO 8601 format.

Comment: @RobG isn't the first format iso? I would come here and check if any if the 'toX' methods works for you. There are quite a few Like toISOString or to toGMTString > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Answer (score 7):

You should transform the strings to dates so that you can perform operations with the dates:

```js
var dt1 = new Date("2020-03-27T16:59:57Z".replace('T', ' ').replace('Z', ''))
var dt2 = new Date("2020-03-27 16:00:00")

function calcDifference(dt1, dt2) {
    var diff = (dt1 - dt2) / 1000;
    diff /= 60;
    return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));
}

console.log(calcDifference(dt1, dt2));
```